# Can I unlock a Bitlocker drive from Windows 10 in Windows 2012R2?

Tags: windows-10, bitlocker, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to unlock a Bitlocker'd external drive on a Windows 2012R2 server, but it is not accepting the password - it just gives the `The password entered is incorrect.` message.

I'm assured the password is correct, so I'm wondering if perhaps it's been encrypted with the XTS-AES encryption method from [Windows 10 1511+](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-1507-and-1511), and we're just getting a misleading error message.

If it has been encrypted in this way, is there anything we can do to unlock or decrypt it without finding a later version of Windows to connect it to?

Answer (score 0):

> If it has been encrypted in this way, is there anything we can do to unlock or decrypt it without finding a later version of Windows to connect it to?

What you want is not possible.  If you encrypted the drive while running a newer version of Windows 10, then the drive was encrypted using a schema, that Windows Server 2012R2 does not support.

This means you will have to decrypt the drive using the same version of Windows 10 you used to encrypt the drive, and instead of using a Windows 10 installation to encrypt the drive again, use Windows Server 2012R2 to encrypt the drive.  This will allow the drive to be encrypted in order to support both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2012R2.

**The encryption schema that BitLocker uses cannot be changed without first decrypting the drive.**

> we're just getting a misleading error message.

If you are talking about the error message indicating the password was incorrect, that actually is accurate, since the password is indeed incorrect due to the schema used to encrypt the drive isn't the same as the scheme being used to decrypt the drive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that an older version of BitLocker may well be entirely unable to validate a password for a newer schema. But if the password is indeed correct, something saying the password is incorrect cannot be “accurate”.

Comment: @mwfearnley - The password is used to decrypt the password.  BitLocker is able to determine the expected result has not been achieved.  This incorrect status happens when the incorrect password is provided.  It's the incorrect password due to the incorrect decryption schema being used.

Comment: Hmm, I don’t follow with your logic, but I think I maybe see what you’re getting at: since the schema is unsupported, there can be no such thing as a correct password, therefore, the password must be “incorrect” by definition?

Comment: The password is require to decrypt the data, the password is only correct, if the same algorithm that was used to encrypt the data is used to decrypt the data.  BitLocker only knows if the blob was successfully decrypted, there is no way to determine the difference between, an incorrect password and the incorrect decryption schema both have the same results when the decryption process fails.